# "Cocos2d-Javascript" or "Cocos2d-x html5", which one is better for HTML5 Development?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, cocos2d-iphone

I want to use Cocos2d family of framework for Html5 Mobile development, but I found there are two frameworks, "Cocos2d-Javascript" and "Cocos2d-x Html5", which one should I choose?

Answer (score 1):

Cocos2d Html5 is your best choice.

Read this for more info: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Cocos2d-html5

Answer (score 0):

Today both are merging their APIs to offer code portability between cocos2d-html5 and cocos2d-x with javascript bindings.

So you will see less and less difference in the code you write for the latest versions of those two frameworks. I work mostly with cocos2d-x with javascript knowing my code is easily adaptable for the web.